# Translucent theme with material

Tags: android, themes

I'm trying to create transitions in my application and it looks bad since the background color of my "android:windowBackground" (white) is flashing for a few ms when I change activity.

Managed to remove it with the Translucent Theme (parent="android:Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"), but Translucent does not seem to be an option when using the Material theme. Is there any way to combine those themes?